# What are all the error messages of the echo command?

Tags: c, shell, error-handling, command, echo

I'm searching for all the errors messages of the echo command.

I need to implement echo in my own shell.

I already searched for the errors online, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Find source codes of Bash, then look in `echo.c`. Why do you need it though, if it is *your own shell* ?

Comment: There are no errors from the `echo` command.  It repeats what it is given as arguments, with the arguments separated by spaces.  The shell might report problems forming the argument list, but once `echo` is executing, there isn't any room for errors.  Of course, it might depend on which variant of `echo` you're emulating/implementing.  POSIX [`echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) for XSI does have some `\x` escapes; you might get an error from those.  Consider using [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) instead.

Comment: Instead of trying to emulate the messaging and message list of a particular `echo` implementation, how about just implementing the needed functionality and emitting error messages as appropriate to *that*?  Catch the error codes of all syscalls, and when they indicate a failure that must be reported, emit a message.  If `errno` is set by that function, then consider using `perror()` to emit the message -- then you don't even need to come up with your own message text.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Not quite true.  There is still room for error after echo executes. eg `$ /bin/echo foo >&-` results in 
`/bin/echo: write: Bad file descriptor`

Comment: @WilliamPursell: yeah — that exception didn't fit into 600 characters with the rest of my comment. But if you've closed stdout, you're likely to have multiple problems, and if you go explicitly closing stdout just for `echo`, you're suffering from delusions of some sort (about what's useful). More interesting would be an error from appending to a file that fills the disk and generates the appropriate 'no space left' message. Running out of inodes would be a shell error — the redirection would fail, not the `echo` command (which wouldn't be run). I should have said "much room" instead of "any".